# How would I answer the following question about the determinant and adjugate of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, adjoint-operators

"Let A be a 3 x 3 matrix with determinant 4. Then det(adj(${A^T)) = ?, det(adj(A^{-1}))}$ = ? and det(adj(4A)) = ?."

Are there any rules through which I can solve this? The fact that their are adjoints and determinants together is confusing me.

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Do mean the adjoint or the adjugate matrix?

Comment: Adjoint. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: I am actually sure that you mean the adjugate. How do you define $adj(A)$?

Comment: Ok yes you are right! My apologies! I had never come across the term adjugate before so I was not sure!

Comment: In your first comment you seemed to be very sure. You could at least have looked that up immediately.

Answer (score 0):

The adjugate matrix satisfies:

1. $A^{-1}=\frac{1}{\det(A)} \text{adj}(A)$

Use (1) and the following properties of the determinant of a square matrix with dimensionality $n$:

- $\det(A^{\top})=det(A)$
- $\det(A^{-1})=\frac{1}{\det(A)}$.
- $\det(cA)=c^n \det(A)$